# Last updated post in wordpress homepage first position

Tags: posts

Please let me know how to display last updated post in wordpress homepage first position.

Regards,
LeeryFox

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the intended result, you must change the sorting from default by date of publication to the modification date. To do this, you can use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter hook, the appropriate value for the `orderby` query parameter can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). To apply changes only on the home page, the conditional tag [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) will be used.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'se338231_home__sort_by_modified_date' );
function se338231_home__sort_by_modified_date( $query )
{
    if ( !is_home() || !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
}
```

Comment: Required functions.php code

Comment: @LeeryFox I do not really understand. Do not have access to `functions.php`?

Comment: When I edit a post, the publish date should be replace with edited date. We required functions.php script for that.

Comment: @LeeryFox Check your second question.

Comment: That code not working.